# I've printed the Ascii characters of a string, how do i add the values together?

Tags: c#, .net

So I got this:

```
string name = "";
int sum = 0;
Console.WriteLine("What's you name?");
name = Console.ReadLine();
foreach (char c in name)
{
    Console.WriteLine((int)c);
}
sum = Console.ReadKey();
```

Now my question is, how do I add the values of all characters' ASCII codes?

Comment: `sum += (int)c; Console.WriteLine((int)c);` in the foreach

Comment: @Oliver , I hope you would have only the  GeorgeA code in the foreach

Comment: @faheemkhan , yes i do, but for some reason i added `Console.WriteLine((int)c);` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be fairly simple;

```
string name = "";
int sum = 0;
Console.WriteLine("What's you name?");
name = Console.ReadLine();
foreach (char c in name)
{
    Console.WriteLine((int)c);
    sum += (int) c; // This line will add all the values together
}
Console.WriteLine(sum.ToString()); // If you want to print to the console the sum.
// sum = // This line will prevent compilation. Does it need removing?
Console.ReadKey();
```

Credit to @George Alexandria.

It may be worth using the GetNumericValue function instead of casting too.
For Example:

```
(int)Char.GetNumericValue(c);
```